# IR LED (VSMY7850x01) 850nm to 750nm

Tags: led, infrared

Currently I am using  VSMY7850x01 IR LED which is 850 nm this IR LED works perfectly for my project however  I want to change 750 nm for optimal quantum efficiency of my lens which is in the 750 nm, I asked Vishay but unfortunately they don't have this 750 nm IR LED. BTW, I am pulsing 5 A for 200 uS for this LED so it must be 5 A peak current.
My application for this is FLASH for taking photo.

If you have any idea which vendor has is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

750 nanometer LEDs are often specified as *near-Infrared* LEDs. Perhaps adding that keyword would get you better product results.

On a cursory search, several products ([1](http://www.epitex.com/products/led_plastic_mold/pdfs/L750-04AU.pdf), [2](http://www.ir-led.de/fileadmin/Specification/surface_mount_leds/SMT750.pdf), [3](http://www.everlight.com/datasheets/Shuen1W_datasheet.pdf)) show up for 735 to 760 nm wavelengths; a specific vendor search is beyond the scope of this site.

Some of these products are available at [Digikey](http://www.DigiKey.com), which should be a useful starting point.

*Edit:

Not knowing your specific application, this is a bit of a wild shot:

Have you considered 750 nm NIR diode lasers instead of the LEDs? For instance: [1](http://www.nanoplus.com/download/750_830nm_01.pdf), [2](http://www.saillaser.com/750nm%20Diode%20Laser.htm).*

Answer (score 0):

As IR wavelength drops and material changes the Vf increases, so while your lens efficiency improves the emitter efficiency drops significantly, requiring much larger more expensive parts to dissipate the heat. The lowest Vf LEDs are 1.2V at continuous rated current. How much can you afford to pay to gain lens efficiency is the bigger question. Also how important is the reflection coefficient vs nm wavelength?

Comment: If you find a 750nm LED in the same package that can handle 5A, I'll delete my answer. (eat my words)

Comment: It may not be necessarily 750nm it can be 730-770nm. I checked on some distributor it is capable of 1A pulse current. I'm just wondering if somebody who knows the same specs that can handle 5A can suggest but if you say there is nothing like that in the market then I would believe.